# Contact form 7 'submit button' alignment issue

Tags: css

When in edit mode the 'submit button' is correctly in the middle with the rest of the form but when in preview mode the button is to the left. (See pictures)

[Picture 1 - in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ1nd.png)

[Picture 2 - preview mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX56G.png)

Not sure what I've done wrong or need to do with the CSS but I've attached it.

PS. i am new to coding and learning still. If you would like to help clean up and give me a few pointers or suggestions ill take it.

website: https://flyusa.com.au/

```
/* Submit Button CF7 CSS Styles */

.wpcf7 input[type=submit] {
    padding:10px 10px; 
    background:#3387C7;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 70%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Label Text Contact Form 7 CSS Styles */

.wpcf7 label {
   padding: 0 0 0px 0;
   margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#fff;
    
}
/* Text Input Field Contact Form 7 Styles */

.wpcf7 input[type=text], .wpcf7 input[type=email], .wpcf7 input[type=url], .wpcf7 input[type=tel], .wpcf7 input[type=number], .wpcf7 .wpcf7-select {
    color: grey;
    width: 70%;
    font-size:14px;
    border: 2px solid #3387C7;
    }
/* Textarea Field CF7 CSS Styles */

.wpcf7 textarea {
    width: 70%;
    height:100px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 2px solid #3387C7;
}
/* Overall Form CF7 Styles */

.wpcf7 {
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
}

/* Change the width a drop down menu */

.wpcf7 .wpcf7-select {
   width:70%; /* you can use pixels, em, rem, % to determine the width */
   font-size:14px;
   margin: auto;
   
}
.wpcf7 .wpcf7-form-control:not(.wpcf7-submit):not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]) {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
/* Thank you message CSS styles */

.wpcf7-response-output {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color:#3387C7;
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: The spinner to the right of the button is taking up space. If you try moving it then the button will center align.

Comment: So how do i fix that? @rawnewdlz

Answer (score 1):

The Submit button and select fields have margins that are pushing them out of line. Overriding those margin properties will help center them.

```
/* reset button & select field - center */
.wpcf7 input[type=submit],
.wpcf7 .wpcf7-select {margin: 0 auto;}
```

Set the spinner that is next to the submit button to use display:block so it puts itself on to a new line. Change the css properties of "top" & "left" if you want to move it some where else.

```
/* relocate spinner - below button */
.wpcf7-spinner {display: block;top: 15px;left: 45%;}
```

Temporarily add this to view the spinner's placement.

```
.wpcf7-spinner {visibility: visible;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to tell you that you had added span right after your submit button that is creating a trouble in aligning the button.

### How It Works :

For example You have an element of 100px (input[type=submit] button) in `<p></p>` tag and if yo add one more element of 24px (span as a spinner class) then the width of `<p></p>` tag will 124px and a margin of 24px from left and right then the width of will be 172px from 124px.

Simply if you add text in your facebook story or whatsapp status the text will be increase as you enter more word meanwhile the text will arrange its position in center and the text remain also in center as the it occupy more space from left and right side.

Similarly, In your case yo added span with 24px width and 24px margin from left and right (48px as total) And in result your button moved to the left side.

If you want to check some demo just remove the margin from the spinner you will gain your very close result that you had expected [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX56G.png).

### What's the solution

Alright, we have discussed too much boring theory here It's show time

First, If you just remove the margin from `.wpcf7 input[type=submit]` and put `left: 24px;` after `position: relative;` in `.wpcf7-spinner`. Trust me that will work perfect.

Second, just add `margin-left: 24px;` to deal with  the width of `.wpcf7-spinner`. Trust me this will also work perfect.

Third, this will enough to boom.

Finally the code will:

```
    .wpcf7 input[type=submit] {
        margin-left: 24px;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        background: #3387C7;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 0 none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 70%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .wpcf7-spinner {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #23282d;
    opacity: 0.75;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    /* margin: 0 24px; */
    position: relative;
    left: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. now its to far to the right.

Comment: I understand I do and thankyou. unfortunately, it didn't work that's all. I did exactly, I copy pasted it in over the current CSS.

Comment: But it works in my browser i have tested and at the end i had pasted it from my browser

Comment: you had not pasted it correctly i think i had tested it and margin-left will be same as your width of span of class spinner

Comment: :( well im not sure then. The button is now a bit to the right now. In fact the whole contact form isn't center. I guess I've got something wrong. Im checking on both mobile and browser.